# How to set programmatically recipients of Jenkins Email-ext plugin?

Tags: email, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set the recipients of the `Email-ext` (aka `Editable Email Notficiation`) to the owners of failed tests. Since the owners can't be calculated until after a build fails, the `Inject Environment Variables` plugin can't be used.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Advanced...` section create the following `Pre-send Script`:

```
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress('recipient@example.com'))
```

You'll also need to set `Project Recipient List` (maybe to some dummy value) since if it's empty, the plugin decides there's nothing to do.

The script runs on the master so you'll need to `ssh` onto the slave from the master if you need to process its workspace.

Comment: After adding this the default subject line is missing

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read list of recipients from file on remote agent, expand above answer with FilePath:

```
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

fp = new FilePath(build.workspace, build.workspace.toString() + "/recipients.txt")
emails = fp.readToString().split("\n")

for (email in emails) {
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent Jenkins versions (e.g. 2.3), importing "javax.mail.Message" in email-ext script, might fail on:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.addRecipients() is applicable for
> argument types: (javax.mail.Message$RecipientType, java.lang.String)

In such case, import "***jakarta.mail.Message***" instead, and then you can set emails with a simple String:

```
import jakarta.mail.Message
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "first@email.com,second@email.com")
```