# How do i programatically set the email recipients for a jenkins job

Tags: email, jenkins, bulk

I am trying to update the email recipients for loads of jenkins job with new set of email lists, I am unable to find the right API to do so. Although this could be updated in the config file directly but wanted to use Jenkins APIs if available any

Edit : I am referring to the below field
Post-build Actions: E-mail Notification > Recipients

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set programmatically recipients of Jenkins Email-ext plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601776/how-to-set-programmatically-recipients-of-jenkins-email-ext-plugin)

Comment: @Tim: My question is to update all the jobs with new set of recipients. I need to get an API to update the recipients. Where as in the link provided , the msg object is already available. also the other question is related to Editable Email notifications , which is a plugin for Jenkins. What i am asking is regarding the default email notification

Answer (score 1):

Well. Currently I do not have the code but I have the thoughts.

**1st step:**
You can use whatever jenkins API (REST, python wrapper,etc...) to dump all your job names into a txt file, saying `job_list.txt`. 
Below is an example. And you can find the useage from [This link](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html).

```
import jenkins
j = jenkins.Jenkins('http://your_url_here', 'username', 'password')
j.get_jobs()
```

**2nd step:**
    As you can see, each job has an config file with path like `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/job_name/config.xml`. This can also be accessed from your browser. From browser it looks like this:

[image: recipients shows in jenkins job's config.xml]

So your question can be simplified into either:
"**How to update the recipients value of config.xml from each job folder under `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` directory**".
Or:
"**How to update the recipients value of config.xml from each job url like `http://your_jenkins_url/job/each_job_name/config.xml`**".

So this can be done by any script language like `python`,`ruby`,`shell`,`vb` or whatever http-like lib like 'urllib2', 'requests' etc...

**3rd step:**
After all the config.xml file updated, don't forget to restart your jenkins to take effects.

Good luck, buddy!

---

**Edited(2015-05-27)**
There is an existing Groovy script written by @edalquist which can update the email address in a programatically way. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/updateEmailAddress.groovy

Comment: thanks for your answer. As an alternative i checked this option. But i was wondering if there are any API to do this. What you mentioned could be done without scripts. just open them in text editor and replace all.. i was thinking in terms of scriptlets.

Comment: I don't see any such specific API that can do this. You are absolutely correct, The method I mentioned can be done by using something like `sed` command. Anyway, if you come up with a scriptlets solution, do be shy to share with us. Thank you.

Comment: I've found an groovy script which I think what you are looking for: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/updateEmailAddress.groovy

Comment: thanks @mainframer. that does solve the question. Just a minor change, we need to save the job after assigning the new email address. you may update your answer with this link